# Tone down the duplicate warning on creating a new chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

### Background

When creating a new chat room there is an IMPORTANT note about avoiding creating duplicates (see screenshot). Taken literally it is a perfectly fine message. But the way its written it gives the impression that creating a new room is a *big* deal.

This was relevant (quite a while back when I was a low rep user) when I was involved in a 3 way comment discussion that was dragging on, but because it was a 3 way conversation the "move to chat" notification never appeared. I decided to create a manual chat room, however I took that message very seriously and assumed the "auto chat conversion" was a separate system. Having been scared off creating a new room I continued with the long running comment discussion in comments; not ideal behaviour.

### Request

Could the message when creating a room be toned down. Perhaps something along the lines of:

> If creating a room about a specific subject please check for an existing
> similar room before creating a new one; duplicate or inactive rooms
> may be deleted.

[image]

I'm looking at this with an aim to move more tangential discussions to chat rather than in long comment chains

Comment: Really seems fine to me.  Maybe just the ALL CAPS `IMPORTANT: ` could be dropped.

Comment: @superScript yes, I think the all caps IMPORTANT is the main problem